# How do I use URL parameters to filter a channel by a date field?

Tags: templating, datetime, filter

How do I filter entries by URL parameters. The url is `/booking?month=november&year=2015`.

So far I have:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('availability').order('availabilityStartDate').limit(null) %}
```

where `availabilityStartDate` is a date field.

How do I return entries that match November and 2015.

Thanks for any ideas or code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pull query string variables using the [HttpRequestService](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpRequestService), like this:

```
{% set month = craft.request.query('month') %}
{% set year = craft.request.query('year') %}
```

Then, you'll need to construct a DateTime object from those query parameters:

```
{% set queryDate = date([month, year]|join(' ')) %}
```

...and finally, include that date object in the criteria for `craft.entries` (notice the `>=` operator, which means we should get entries with a `availabilityStartDate` value equal or higher to the `queryDate` date object:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('availability').order('availabilityStartDate').availabilityStartDate('>= ' ~ queryDate.date).limit(null) %}
```

**EDIT**

Filtering out entries with date field values matching the queried month and year *exactly* is a bit more complicated.

There are probably several ways to approach this, but a thing that works is to use both a start date (i.e. the first day of the queried month) as well as an end date (i.e. the last day of the queried month) for the criteria.

Being that the `queryDate` variable actually already refers to the first day of the queried month, we'll just need to add 1 month for the end date:

```
{% set queryStartDate = date([month, year]|join(' ')) %}
{% set queryEndDate = queryStartDate.date|date_modify('+1 month') %}
```

And here's the element criteria with both date object statements:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('availability ').order('availabilityStartDate').availabilityStartDate('and', '>= ' ~ queryStartDate.date, '< ' ~ queryEndDate.date).limit(null) %}
```

Here's everything together, for cohesion:

```
{# Get month and year query parameters #}
{% set month = craft.request.query('month') %}
{% set year = craft.request.query('year') %}

{# Create DateTime objects for the start date and end date (+1 month) #}
{% set queryStartDate = date([month, year]|join(' ')) %}
{% set queryEndDate = queryStartDate.date|date_modify('+1 month') %}

{# Get the entries #}
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('availability ').order('availabilityStartDate').availabilityStartDate('and', '>= ' ~ queryStartDate.date, '< ' ~ queryEndDate.date).limit(null) %}
```

PS: When you have multiple parameters to `craft.entries` like this, you might want to consider the object syntax for readability:

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries({
    section : 'availability',
    order : 'availabilityStartDate',
    availabilityStartDate : 'and, >= ' ~ queryStartDate.date ~ ', < ' ~ queryEndDate.date,
    limit : null
}) %}
```

Comment: Hi mmikkel, thanks for taking the time to answer me - much appreciated. I've used {% for entry in allEntries %} {{ entry.availabilityStartDate | date ("j F Y") }}<br>{% endfor %} to output the entries that should have month=november and year=2015.The output includes all entries in december 2015, but is also including january 2016, february 2016 - whereas I only want entries where month=november and year=2015. Got any ideas, I've tried several things to no avail.

Comment: Aha, I didn't catch that detail, sorry. You'll want to use the `=` operator over `>=`, but you'll also need to normalize the dates. I'm in a rush right now but I'll look at it later if you don't get another answer (or an edit) :)

Comment: Hi mmikkel, when you've got a moment help with normalizing the dates would be great. Have a good weekend!

Comment: Hello @user1070143 – check out the edit, hopefully this will work out for you. A good weekend to you to!

Comment: Hi mmikkel, thank you very much for the time and expertise you put into answering my questions. If you care to drop me your paypal email I'd like to buy you a bottle of wine.

Comment: @user1070143 Haha, thanks – the offer is much appreciated but totally not necessary :) You can buy me a beer if we ever meet at a Craft conference ;)

Comment: Someone said beer/wine?

Comment: Yes. And "Craft conference" :)